# Повторное сравнение типов

Tags: javascript, консоль

Почему при повторном сравнении типов, на любом массиве даёт:  `typeof typeof arr === 'string'`. С чем это связано?

Comment: А какой результат Вы ожидали получить?

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-typeof-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) оператор `typeof` возвращает строку.

Поэтому повторное применение `typeof` к результату всегда даст `'string'`